# Closed-source framework with resources and dependencies

Tags: ios, cocoapods, swift-package-manager, xcframework

I would like to create a framework with these constraints:

- code is closed to integrator
- the framework in itself is modularized. Example of modules:

```
    FeatureA      FeatureB      3rd party dependency (ex. a Swift Package or Cocoapod)
        ^             ^             ^
        |             |             |
        |_____________|_____________|
                      |
                    Core                    // client would integrate this
                      ^
                      |
                      UI                    // or this
```

in this example, I'd like to be able to build independently Core or UI.

- Framework includes 3rd party dependencies and should be hidden from integrator
- Framework contains many languages (Swift, Obj-c, Obj-c++ and c++)
- Framework contains assets and localization
- Included architectures: iOS device, simulator (both Intel and M1 arch versions)
- Minimal SDK: 13.2

---

I have tried many approaches, but always hit a roadblock. For example, an `XCFramework` doesn't seem to be able to include successfully 3rd party.
`SPM` doesn't seem to support *exporting* as binary.
`Aggregated framework`: not sure how to include a cocoapod as dependent target.

Many of the posts I've read are quite old and refer to concepts I'm not sure still exists, like `Fake Framework` or `Umbrella Framework`.

So my question is this: what is the best approach, in today's environment, for these constraints? If XCFramework really is the best approach, how can we include 3rd party dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good solution available.
[XCFramework with Pods Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64645642/xcframework-with-pods-dependencies)

There is one issue though, third party dependancies. For third party dependencies, you have to add third party dependencies manually instead of pod. Also remember to remove their `public` header or just remove `public` keyword so that they are not accessible.